# How to set Custom range to an CalendarView in Android?

Tags: android

I want to limit the calenderview from current date to next 90 days in android but I am unable to use `setMaxDate()` and `setMinDate()` method for my requirements, what should I follow to set Custom range?

Answer (score 1):

add view in your xml layout.

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></CalendarView>
```

in java

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 90);
        calendarView.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```